# Deleting/Refreshing custom list adapter for new data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a ListView populated with custom adapters every time data is downloaded. The problem is every the onResume calls the download method, the views are duplicated instead of removing old views and replacing with new ones.

How can I fix stop the duplication? below is my code, I attempted making a method to be deleting views but I do not think its working fine or better yet complete.

```
  public class CommentAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ViewHolder holder;
public CommentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
this.listData = listData;
notifyDataSetChanged();
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return listData.get(position); 
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 if (convertView == null) {
 convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlecomment, null);
 holder = new ViewHolder();
 holder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernme);
 holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postCommentBox);
 holder.timeStamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeAgo);

 convertView.setTag(holder);

} else {
  holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

 ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
 holder.username.setText(newsItem.getUsername());
 holder.message.setText(newsItem.getmComment());
  holder.timeStamp.setText(newsItem.getTimeStamp());

 return convertView;
 }


 //method to delete old views i tried implementing
 //from each adapter
 public void deleteOldViews(){
 listData.clear();
 this.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

 static class ViewHolder {
 TextView username;
TextView message;
TextView timeStamp;

 }
```

}
   //Implementation of the CustomAdapter

```
 //ListAdapter
  private void updateList() {
// Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
ArrayList<ListItem> listData = getListData();
   final ListView listView = getListView();
     listView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(new CommentAdapter(PostComments.this, listData));
    AsyncTask
```

class LoadAuto extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    int success;


    try {


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postID", postID));

        //Posting user data to script
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                LOAD_COMMENT_URL, "POST", param);

        // full json response
        Log.d("Post Comment attempt", json.toString());

        // json success element
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Comment Added!", json.toString());

            //Updating Json
            mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            try {

                //check connection before search for posts
                mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

                // looping through all posts according to the json object       returned
                for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                    // gets the content of each tag;
                    // gets the content of each tag;
                    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIMESTAMP);
                    content = c.getString(TAG_COMMENT);
                    username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);

                    //getting comments

                    mUsername.add("By " + username);
                    TimeStamp.add(time);
                    Comment.add(content);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            Log.d("Comment Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        //Handle Exception

        String s = "NullPointerException";
        return s;


    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}


protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


 //Updating List
        updateList();
     ;
    }


}
```

getlistdata method

```
   private ArrayList<ListItem> getListData() { 
  ArrayList<ListItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
   String[] username = mUsername.toArray(new String[mUsername.size()]);
  String[] comments = Comment.toArray(new String[Comment.size()]); 
  String[] time = TimeStamp.toArray(new String[TimeStamp.size()]);

  for (int i = 0; i < username.length; i++) {
      ListItem newsData = new ListItem();
      newsData.setUsername(username[i]); 
      newsData.setmComment(comments[i]);
       newsData.setTimeStamp(time[i]);
        listMockData.add(newsData); 
         System.gc();
      } 
      return listMockData;
        }
```

Comment: You can just clear the list or re initiate it in onResume().

Could you post getListData(); method code?

Comment: i have added the getlistdata method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think its a global variable, thats direct creation of a instance of a class, and since its a listadapter, it is directly assigned to the listview, what U think should be done is making the adapter a global variable then calling the .notifyDataSetChanged() before setting any data, then setting the adapter and giving it the right data it needs.

```
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    adapter = new CommentAdapter(this,listData);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i still cannot make it work, I tried but it still duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to declare global adapter variable and not to create new one each time you set listview adapter .

```
CommentAdapter commentAdapter;
```

then in updateList() method

```
commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(PostComments.this, listData);
listView.setAdapter(commentAdapter );
```

using this code , you will not lose reference to your adapter, hope this help

Answer (score -1):

try simply using `listView.setAdapter(null);` to empty the `ListView` and then set your adapter again.